# Partitioning join to limit records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial

I have 2 tables:
- first one containing spatial data - geometry of circles
- second contains geometries of lines.

I want to find all lines which are inside each circle. I have a query which can do that, however there are millions of records so it is unusably slow. 
There is a column in both tables which is area_id and essentially all circles are assigned to particular area and all lines as well, so **if I can do the intersect of the circles only with the lines in the matching area this will reduce the load a lot**. The problem is I can't think of solution e.g. using windowing function. The query I am using is:

```
Select ct.AREA_ID, ct.Circle_descr,  lt.Line_descr from circles_table as ct
JOIN lines_table as lt
ON 
circles_table.Circle_location.STIntersects(points_table.Point_location)=1
```

*using a where clause at the end makes no difference as it is essentially part of the slow join...

```
+---------------+----------------------+--------------------------+
| AREA_ID (int) | Circle_descr(varchar) | Circle_location(geometry)|
+---------------+----------------------+--------------------------+


+---------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| AREA_ID (int) | Line_descr(varchar) | Line_location(geometry) |
+---------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Please post table DDL, sample data and desired results.

Comment: the desired result is already achieved by the query - the issue is the performance

Comment: That SQL Query is invalid, and that's not DDL.  But basically just add a JOIN clause limiting the join to rows in the same area.  Something like  `and ct.area_id = lt.area_id`.

Comment: The SQL server is on network without internet and the data is sensitive so can't post the exact query and sample data. I have given those only as example as I need an idea not a ready to use answer. Limiting the Join that way wouldn't help - I actually tried and the performance is exactly the same, as it still has to go through all the records to join the tables and depending on the query plan it may end up doing the intersect first so won't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional join criterion to partition the rows by area_id before comparing them.  Something like

```
Select ct.AREA_ID, ct.Circle_descr,  lt.Line_descr 
from circles_table as ct
JOIN lines_table as lt
  ON ct.Circle_location.STIntersects(lt.Point_location)=1
 AND ct.area_id = lt.area_id
```